# Assigning child object to parent object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I am running below java code and I can't figure out why it is returning 0 as output instead of 200 or 500.

```
class Bike{
  int speedlimit;
 }
 class Honda3 extends Bike{
  int speedlimit;
 
  public static void main(String args[]){
   Bike obj=new Bike();
   obj.speedlimit=200;
   Honda3 obj2=new Honda3();
   obj2.speedlimit=500;
   obj=obj2;
  System.out.println(obj.speedlimit);
 }
}
```

*Output: 0*

1. I though that **obj=obj2** will work like  runtime polymorphism but it seems that my reasoning is not correct. Not sure what I am missing here.
2. I have not used **obj=obj2** kind of code myself before and I was thinking if there is a scenario where it can be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an object of `Honda3`, The created object also includes all the fields of Parent class i.e `Bike`. All the field are initialized with their default value(`speedlimit = 0`). Also during object creation, We can't discard the `speedlimit` field of Bike just because `Honda3` has the field with same name. We are not telling compiler to override the field so compiler will include both the `speedlimit` fields inside `Honda3` object like this-

- speedlimit(from Bike) <= Hidden
- speedlimit

So if you assigning the `Honda3` object to a variable of type `Bike` then you can access the hidden `speedlimit` via that variable. Please refer to the below image to visualize the whole process-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing 0 because you are using two separated speedlimit attributes, one for Bike class and another for Honda3 class, you can just remove the attribute from Honda3 class because it is inheriting it from Bike class.

In this line `obj.speedlimit` you are assigning the Bike attribute, and in the other hand `obj2.speedlimit` is assigning the Honda3 attribute.
When you assign `obj = obj2` and then access the speedlimit attribute from `obj`, you are no longer using the attribute from Honda3 class but the one in Bike class, which was not assigned yet.

If you remove the speedlimit attribute from Honda3 class your problem will disapear.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a field in subclass that has the same name as a field in the super class then you don't override the field but only "hide" it to users of the subclass.

Thus when you create a Honda3 you create an object with two speedlimit fields: the field of the Bike class is initialized to zero (because that is the default for ints) and the field of the Honda3 class is set to 200. Then when you "use" the Honda3 as "Bike", the speedlimit field of the Bike class is no longer hidden and is printed to standard out.

Answer (score 0):

Because `obj2 = obj` assigns a `Honda3` instance with a hidden field `Bike.speedlimit` which is initialized as a default of `0`

1. A `new Bike()` with a `speedlimit` instance variable of `0` is created then assigned `200`
2. A `new Honda3()` is created with instance variable `speedlimit = 0` and a `Bike.speedlimit = 0` which is inherits from `Bike` then `speedlimit` is assigned `500`. `Honda3` is hiding the `Bike` `speedlimit`

When you assign `obj = obj2` you perform an upcast and reference the `Honda` as a `Bike` and `System.out.prinln(obj.speedlimit)` prints the `Bike.speedlimit` conversely if you were to do a downcast `System.out.println(((Honda3) obj).speedlimit)` you would get `500`

Also runtime polymorphism or dynamic dispatch only works for methods not data members. Methods are overriden, but fields are hidden.

[image]

**After** `obj = obj2`

[image]